# Non-trivial Examples of Surfaces of Voss

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, surfaces, geodesic, minimal-surfaces

Let $I$ and $J \subset \mathbb{R}$ be two intervals of the real line. A smooth parametrized immersed surface $\sigma: I\times J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is called a surface of Voss if its coordinate curves satisfy the following conditions:

- They form a conjugate net (i.e. $\sigma_{uv} \in \textrm{span}\{\sigma_u, \sigma_v\}$),
- They are two one-parameter families of geodesics.

I'm looking for non-trivial examples (non-developable surfaces) of this kind. I would be very much interested in a non-minimal example too.

**My Attempt:**
I know that there are ways of making them using their relation to a pseudospherical surface but all of them involve solving systems of PDEs and I wish to know if one has a "relatively simple" example of these surfaces.

Comment: @TedShifrin how did you derive orthogonal coordinate curves from the conjugate net? The conjugate net means that the 2nd fundamental form is diagonal (if written in a matrix form) not the 1st fundamental form.

Comment: @TedShifrin why should the geodesics be lines of curvature? A necessary and sufficient condition for the coordinate curves to be lines of curvature is that the matrix form of 1st and 2nd fundamental forms be diagonal at the same time. A non-developable V-surface  is just diagonal in the 2nd fundamental form.

Comment: Oh, agh, I was still thinking the first fundamental form is diagonal. I will erase all my comments ;P

Comment: (+1) Just a note for posterity: Eisenhart, in [_Transformations of Surfaces of Voss_](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1914-015-03/S0002-9947-1914-1500978-X/S0002-9947-1914-1500978-X.pdf) (Trans. AMS 1914) does not mention elementary examples of the type requested.